# Conditional bind property fxFlex in Angular 9

Tags: javascript, html, angular, flexbox, angular-flex-layout

I am using the Angular flexlayout which works perfectly, I am trying to bind fxFlex to the child element like below

```
<div [fxLayout]="fields.layoutConfig.fxLayout + ' wrap'" fxLayoutGap="10px">
    <div *ngFor="let field of fields.componentConfig;" [fxFlex]="field?.componentProperty?.fxFlexChildLayout?.fxFlex">
        <ng-container reactiveField [field]="field" [group]="form"></ng-container>
    </div>
</div>
```

Whenever the  `field?.componentProperty?.fxFlexChildLayout?.fxFlex` is null or undefined it should not bind fxFlex to the div

I have tried

`[fxFlex]="field?.componentProperty?.fxFlexChildLayout?.fxFlex != undefined ? field?.componentProperty?.fxFlexChildLayout?.fxFlex : 'null'"`

```
[attr.fxFlex]="field?.componentProperty?.fxFlexChildLayout?.fxFlex" --> this does nothing it doesn't bind `fxFlex` when it has value as well
```

But still in the DOM I can see it add the style as

```
style="flex: 1 1 100%; box-sizing: border-box;"
```

I don't want to add style if the value of `field?.componentProperty?.fxFlexChildLayout?.fxFlex` is undefined or null

How can I achieve this ?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot conditionally apply a directive is the issue.  You can dynamically set the value of a directive input which is what you are doing above, but all divs will have the fxFlex directive.

So:

```
  <div [fxLayout]="fields.layoutConfig.fxLayout + ' wrap'" fxLayoutGap="10px">
  <ng-container *ngIf="field?.componentProperty?.fxFlexChildLayout?.fxFlex; else noFxFlex">
    <div *ngFor="let field of fields.componentConfig;" [fxFlex]="field?.componentProperty?.fxFlexChildLayout?.fxFlex">
      <ng-container reactiveField [field]="field" [group]="form"></ng-container>
    </div>
  </ng-container>
  <ng-template #noFxFlex>
    <div *ngFor="let field of fields.componentConfig;">
      <ng-container reactiveField [field]="field" [group]="form"></ng-container>
    </div>
  </ng-template>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This isn't the answer you asked for, but as @Randy stated in their answer because you can't conditionally apply a directive, an alternative solution would be to pass "none" to the `[fxFlex]` directive.

"None" should size the child element according to its width and height properties. It is fully inflexible. It neither shrinks nor grows in relation to the flex container.

That should have the same effect as removing the `[fxFlex]` directive, however, the DOM element will still have some flex styles on it.

```
<div [fxLayout]="fields.layoutConfig.fxLayout + ' wrap'" fxLayoutGap="10px">
    <div *ngFor="let field of fields.componentConfig;" [fxFlex]="field?.componentProperty?.fxFlexChildLayout?.fxFlex || 'none'">
        <ng-container reactiveField [field]="field" [group]="form"></ng-container>
    </div>
</div>
```

See https://github.com/angular/flex-layout/wiki/fxFlex-API#fxflex-options

Answer (score 0):

You just need to declare a variable in your TS and assign

HTML

```html
<div fxFlex="{{fxflexwidth}}">
```

TS

```js
fxflexwidth: number = 50;
```

> in your function just return when you need to change the attribute:

```js
this.fxflexwidth = 100;
```